# How to Target Twitter Bootstrap <768px and 480px Breakpoints

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking to understand how i can target screen sizes below 768px and specifically sizes of 480px. I am currently trying to create a page that will show 3 logos for 3 different sites and this works well but falls over when reaching below 768px.

My HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Layout</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="darkbg col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><img src="logo1.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="darkerbg col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><img src="logo2.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="darkestbg col-sm-4 col-xs-12"><img src="logo3.jpg"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
/* custom stylesheet */

.darkbg {
    background: #999;
    text-align:center;
}

.darkbg img, 
.darkerbg img, 
.darkestbg img {
    width:100%;
    }

.darkerbg {
    background: #666;
    text-align:center;
}

.darkestbg {
    background: #333;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The problem lies when I use the class "col-xs-12" as the logos look too large on the screen and this should resemble the col-sm and be spread over 4 columns as col-xs-4. This fixes this issue but when i reach the breakpoint of 480px then the logos look too small and as far as i know the lowest breakpoint is col-xs which targets the screen size of 768px so i am not sure how i am able to fix this issue.

I understand that I can use media queries, but abit confused as to what code I need to write to show each logo on top of each other when reaching the size of 480px.

If somebody could please advise, would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 example Snippets. One of these may help depending on your ultimate requirements and you could always create a custom build of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) too.

Grid Example) You could resize the images @480px etc.

1) Without using the grid: build a simple class to change the display property @480px and resize the images however you want at whatever breakpoint, etc.

2) Same as Example 1 but the images are set at 100% width @480px.

See example Snippet at Full Page.

```css
.darkbg,
.darkbg.img-thumbnail {
  background: #999;
}
.darkerbg,
.darkerbg.img-thumbnail {
  background: #666;
}
.darkestbg,
.darkestbg.img-thumbnail {
  background: #333;
}
/**Grid**/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .img-block {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .img-block img {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
/**One**/

.img-block-one img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .img-block-one img {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
}
/**Two**/

.img-block-two img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .img-block-two img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Grid Example</h2>

  <div class="row img-block">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/eee/000" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail darkbg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/eee/000" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail darkerbg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/eee/000" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail darkestbg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Example One</h2>

  <div class="img-block-one text-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkerbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkestbg" />
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Example Two</h2>

  <div class="img-block-two text-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0/000" class="img-responsive darkbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0/000" class="img-responsive darkerbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/ff0/000" class="img-responsive darkestbg" />
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Heres and example of centering vertically and horizontally. I places the rules inside a media-query so they only work above 480px because it may or may not be beneficial for this sort of display on smaller devices: media query itself can be removed as it doesn't change the anything else. These is also a width component to the new `img-block-one` class that can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.

```css
.darkbg {
  background: #999;
}
.darkerbg {
  background: #666;
}
.darkestbg {
  background: #333;
}
.img-block-one img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
@media(min-width: 481px) {
  .img-block-one {
    width: 65%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .img-block-one img {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-block-one text-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkerbg" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/f00/fff" class="img-responsive darkestbg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks vanburen, example 1 works brilliantly, just the way i wanted. Btw whats the best way to have all the images vertically aligned to the height of page so that it is in the center? Just for my learning so would be keen to learn.

Comment: Glad it's working for you and see the additional answer about centering.

Comment: Thanks vanburen once again, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to give the `.row > .col-*` divs a `display: block` rule for widths below 480px. That will force each of them to take a full row (one above another).

Something like this should work:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .row .col-xs-12 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

(note: *don't know by heart, but it's possible you might need a selector with greater specificity in order to override the default bootstrap rules*)

Useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks shomz, sorry if i sound abit silly. So if i change the col-xs-12 back to col-xs-4 and when reaching size 480px the logos will then stack on top of each other?

Comment: You're welcome, don't be sorry - we're all here to learn. I'm not sure either of them will work below 480px on their own. Whichever you decide to use, make sure you select them in order to apply the display:block rule... maybe you can use `.row div` selector and never worry about the class name.